# SQL - Calculate time difference between ranked sessions

Tags: sql, oracle, date, time, rank

I have some data on users' session length on a website (i.e. time they were active from and to).

It looks something like this:

```
cust_id     dt          started_at          stopped_at          length  rank
10046493    28/10/2015  27/10/2015 23:45    28/10/2015 00:31    00:46   1
10046493    28/10/2015  28/10/2015 00:31    28/10/2015 00:43    00:12   2
10046493    28/10/2015  28/10/2015 00:43    28/10/2015 00:51    00:08   3
10046493    28/10/2015  28/10/2015 17:35    28/10/2015 18:03    00:28   4
```

There could be 1 session a day, but some customers have loads more (e.g. I found one with 85+).

What I need to do is to check the time difference between the end of one session and the start of the next one. If the difference is less than 30 minutes, then I need to count them as one session and calculate the total length, otherwise they should be two separate sessions.

So I need a code that does something like this:

```
if rank2_start > (rank1_stop + 30) then DIFFERENT
if rank2_start < (rank1_stop + 30) then SAME >>>> in this case I also need rank2_stop - rank1_start (i.e. the difference between the two to get the total session length)
```

Because there can be so many sessions a day, it's not an option to do a massive case when listing rank1, rank2, rank3 etc.

Another problem is that someone might have started 6 sessions within half an hour, so they would all need to be calculated as one.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? If it's super-duper complicated or can't be done with the data available, that's fine as well - it would be just a nice plus to my analysis, but not necessary.

Thanks

Comment: With that sample table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: What about `if rank2_start = (rank1_stop + 30)` ?

Comment: Possibly: Get all the records that have been created in the last 30 minutes for each user using datetime constraint. If there is more than 1, then you can count it as the same session, but if there is only 1 then you can go ahead and count is as a new session and apply that logic. Split up the task into those two queries and perform your logic on those two different queries.

Comment: Expected result in the sample data would be: Rank 1, 2 and 3 would become the same session as rank 1's stopped time is the same as rank 2's start time, and rank 2's stopped time is the same as rank 3's. The session length would become 66 minutes. Then rank 4 would become a separate session as it started way after (17 hours) the 3rd stopped. @GovindRai: I'm not sure how that would work for me, I need to go back to the past 12 months in my analysis, so can't use the last 30 minutes constraint. We thought about splitting the day up to 30 minute periods, but wouldn't work